# Wordpress admin theme options get empty and some script error shown after added the google anaytics code

Tags: php, wordpress

I need a small help from you.

Everything was working fine and it still is, but what happened, i added google anaytics code to WP-admin under 'theme options' and all of the sudden, everything under 'theme options' went blank and i can see some code at the bottom of the page same place at backend.

Can you please have a look for the below screenshot and give some solution to solve this.

[image]

Thanks,

Arularasan D.

Comment: You have some kind of syntax error.

Comment: Hi Pieter Goosen,

Can you please explain how to solve this issue in admin side?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question and specify what you have done an show how you added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue in four steps,

```
1. Exported the phpmyadmin sql files.

2. Opened the sql files in text editor and Search the keyword 'google_analytics'.

3. Removed this code :"google_analytics_tracking_code": "<script>\n  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){\n  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),\n  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)\n  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');\n\n  ga('create', 'UA-5772415-2', 'rastergraphix.com.au');\n  ga('send', 'pageview');\n\n</script>"

4. Finally imported the modified sql files in phpmyadmin.
```

Finally the js issue have solved and admin side theme option gets empty had been solved.

Can you please explain how to add the google analytics code in admin theme options window.

Thanks,
Arularasan D.
Senior PHP Programmer.